# BACKEND_SERVICES quota on GCP is limited to 5

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-load-balancer

We hit a limit where we have around 20 cloud run services which needs 20 backend services to be created while configuring google load balancer.

Is more than 5 backend services per project unusual? Our's is microservices architecture and we expect more services down the line too.

We requested for quota increase but unfortunately google team rejected saying to make use of existing limit. This makes google cloud load balancer unusable in our case.

Can someone share alternatives for this limit?

Update:

Load balancer type: **External**
Backend Service: Service which needs to be connected to a host url(+path-matcher)

Deployment: **gcloud cli**

```
gcloud beta compute backend-services create $backend_service_name \
        --global \
        --enable-cdn \
        --cache-mode USE_ORIGIN_HEADERS \
        --protocol HTTPS \
        --description "$description"
```

> ERROR: (gcloud.beta.compute.backend-services.create) Could not fetch
> resource:
>
> - Quota 'BACKEND_SERVICES' exceeded.  Limit: 5.0 globally.

[image]

Comment: For what are the backend service? Cloud Run services? Compute engine? What type of load balancer are you using?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/quotas#backend_services
Backend services we create while linking to a load balancer(External)

Comment: I updated with logs. Please have a look.

Comment: New accounts have quota limits for resources. For backend services, the default is 5. You can request a quota increase. In the Google Cloud Console, go to IAM -> Quotas.

Comment: I requested twice. They are saying me to utilise existing quota

Comment: You should have put that information in your question. If Google denies your quota increase request, there is no magic that Stackoverflow can perform. Only Google can approve quota increases.

Comment: I added the suggested info already

Comment: You now have your answer: Google must approve your request. I would apply again and list the technical requirements that you have in detail. Note: in my experience when a quota increase is declined, you have a credit issue. Review the credit card that you are using (sufficient credit line). Also, try contacting billing support before requesting another quota increase.

Comment: @JohnHanley Thanks John. I still have credit of $2k in my account. Its surprising they are declining as its a very basic requirement.

Comment: I suggest you rewrite your question with the details you are leaving out. $2k in credits from where and which currency? How old is your account? What type of account? etc. etc. If you have a PM sponsoring you, that will make a difference as he/she can help you.

Comment: 2k from startup credits promotion. Its around an year old account.

Answer (score 0):

On my corporate account I can have up to 75 backend services

[image]

But also only 5 on my personal project. Only the support can do something for that.

Comment: I added billing added too but its very strange to see the limit